# How can I use NSViewController for observing if view/window did appear in Cocoa macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

From my last question I get the information that the best way and apple recommended way for observing if a view or window did appear is using NSViewController, so this my codes:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    private var window: NSWindow!
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        let myNSViewController: MyNSViewController = MyNSViewController()

        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.contentViewController = myNSViewController
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
        window.center()
        
    }

}


class MyNSViewController: NSViewController {
    
    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear() {
        print("viewDidAppear")
    }
}
```

But I am getting error of:

> -[NSNib _initWithNibNamed:bundle:options:] could not load the nibName: test.MyNSViewController in bundle NSBundle

How can I solve the issue here?

Comment: IDK how to say this nicely, but from this recent series of questions, I get the sense that you would have a much easier time if you sat down with a more structured resource (book, course, whatever) that walks you through the fundamentals of AppKit programming. I think you'll find it to be a more enjoyable (or at least less-frustrating) experience than trying to trail-and-error your way into learning the basics.

Comment: This particular error her comes from calling `super.init(nibName:bundle:)`, which tries to load your view controller from a storyboard or nih. When you pass a `nil` nib name, it'll default to looking for a nib with the same name as your VC, and when you pass nil bundle, it'll default to looking in your app's main bundle.

Comment: @Alexander: why you do not answer this question?

Comment: I don't have time to format my comment into a full answer right now, but that should point you in the right direction. lmk if you have further questions about it

Comment: This is your fourth question about getting notified when a window appears. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there's an easier way to get there.

Comment: @Willeke: I have an animation that should start right after window did load, because of that I need to know when the window did load.

Comment: It is clear from this and your prior questions that you are trying to do something advanced and uncommon: create an AppKit app without the default xib or storyboard that Xcode includes in the standard macOS app template.  But it is also clear that you don't understand the basics of AppKit, like how `NSViewController` works. You should not expect us to essentially write you a tutorial on how to do your specific project. You need to work through tutorial material that already exists to learn AppKit basics.

Comment: “I have an animation that should start right after window did load”—I guess you mean “after window did appear”. Have you tried starting your animation immediately after you call `window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)`?

Comment: @robmayoff: Not sure what you mean exactly, the code that I am using are in question, when i use my current codes, it makes animation start before window fully did finished lunching and not good looking, how can i use `.makeKeyAndOrderFront` in order starting animation?

Comment: It sounds like you should post the code that you tried, that does `makeKeyAndOrderFront` and then starts the animation. If you post example code that we can actually run to see your problem, you'll be much more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: @robmayoff: If you want show the animation issue here that would be unrelated to this question topic, should i make new question?