# How can make my function marked as @objc works for selector?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want add a NSMenuItem with this code:

```
import Cocoa

class MyTestAppClass {
    
    var closure: () -> Void
    
    init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
    
    @objc func invoke () {
        closure()
    }
    
}

let myTestAppClass: MyTestAppClass = MyTestAppClass(closure: { print("Hello, world!") })

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        buildMainMenu()
        
        buildWindow()
  
    }
    
    private func buildMainMenu() {
        
        let appMainMenu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        
        let mainMenu: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        mainMenu.submenu = NSMenu(title: "MainMenu")
        
        let mainMenuItem0 = NSMenuItem(title: "Test", action: #selector(myTestAppClass.invoke), keyEquivalent: "t")

        mainMenu.submenu?.items = [mainMenuItem0]

        appMainMenu.items = [mainMenu]
        NSApp.mainMenu = appMainMenu

    }
    
    private func buildWindow() {
        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
     
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
    }

 
}
```

Xcode adds my item to menu but it is not active, it is gray and disabled. How can I solve the issue, Xcode does not show me error even. I tried to use `objc_setAssociatedObject` but I could not use it correctly for solving the issue, I am not trying add an extension or any other function to NSMenu to solving the issue, I want to have more generic answer for applying to any view that need selector, like Buttons or other things.

Comment: Ah, I think this is based off my comment on your previous question. It looks like NSMenuItem doesn’t quite use the target/action pattern, in that you can’t set the target, it’s always the responder chain. You can make these objects be part of the responder chain, but that would be odd and finicky. I think you're better off just using regular `@objc` methods on your views, app delegate, etc, which already participate in the responder chain.

Comment: The target class must inherit from `NSObject` and you should set the target of the menu item explicitly. And the instance of `MyTestAppClass` should be in another class.

Comment: @Alexander `NSMenuItem` does use the target/action pattern. You can set the target. If the target is `nil` then it goes to the responder chain.

Comment: @Willeke oh interesting, `action` is available as a property, it’s just not one if the parameters of the initializer. Odd. Nevermind then

Comment: Please don’t make duplicate accounts, Milen https://stackoverflow.com/q/75348877/3141234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your demo:

1. There is no 'main'
2. Need to set a target for the menuItem

The following source code should run in Xcode if you create a swift project and delete the pre-supplied AppDelegate code, copy/paste the following in its place and change the name of 'AppDelegate.swift' to 'main.swift':

```
import Cocoa

class MyTestAppClass {
    var closure: () -> Void
    
    init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }
    
    @objc func invoke() {
        closure()
    }
}

let myTestAppClass: MyTestAppClass = MyTestAppClass(closure: { print("Hello, world!") })

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        buildMainMenu()
        buildWindow()
    }
    
   func buildMainMenu() {
        let appMainMenu: NSMenu = NSMenu()
        let mainMenu: NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        mainMenu.submenu = NSMenu(title: "MainMenu")
        let mainMenuItem0 = NSMenuItem(title: "Test", action: #selector(myTestAppClass.invoke), keyEquivalent: "t")
        mainMenuItem0.target = myTestAppClass
        mainMenu.submenu?.items = [mainMenuItem0]
        appMainMenu.items = [mainMenu]
        NSApp.mainMenu = appMainMenu
    }
    
    func buildWindow() {
        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView], backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.title = "No Storyboard Window"
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
    }
}

let appDelegate = AppDelegate()

// **** Main **** //
let application = NSApplication.shared
application.delegate = appDelegate
application.run()
```

Comment: I tried your given code and looked to my given code in question, the only missing part was `mainMenuItem0.target = myTestAppClass`, why I need to add `(_ sender:AnyObject)` to invoke function since the codes works without it as well, about main file i assume any person that capable to answer this question can figure it out without mentioning it in question. By the way thanks for your help I just need to know why I need `(_ sender:AnyObject)` in my code?

Comment: They keep changing the swift language.  In the old days I had to use it, but it looks like you are correct that we now don't need it.  I will revise my answer.  Thanks for the followup.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot upvote because i am new, you did good job!